# Single big BST vs multiple smaller BSTs? Which is faster?

Tags: performance, big-o, time-complexity

I am storing `10^9` keys in a BST.
Compared to having lets say having multiple BSTs of size `10^6` containing chunk of the bigger tree? Search through all of them executing in parallel.

I am talking about only search performance here, Given that processing power is not a bottle neck.

Comment: The keys are integers from `0-10^9`

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on your key schema.

For example, let's say your keys are surnames, equally distributed across the twenty-six English letters. If you're looking for `Pax Diablo`, you can immediately remove 25/26ths of your search space, looking only in the `D` tree (for `Diablo`).

With a balanced binary tree, you would have to traverse about `4.7` tree levels on average (`log226` is *about* `4.700439718`).

So, yes, it *can* be more efficient, provided the up-front operation has minimal complexity. In the given example, the selection of one of twenty-six tress is `O(1)`, based on the first character of the name and an array lookup to find the tree.

---

In the case where the keys are actually numbers from zero to a billion as your comments indicate, you could still have the same efficiency, depending on data distribution. If they're equally distributed (or even close), you could maintain a thousand different trees (from your statement that you want trees of size one million) based on the first three digits of the number and reduce the initial search by a factor of 1000 (about ten tree levels).

Of course, the distribution is important. If all your numbers turn out to be less that a million, they'll all be in the first tree and this scheme will save you nothing (in fact it'll add a useless first step).

Comment: The keys are integers from `0-10^9`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a hash table. Look up for such big keyset should be noticably faster. A hashmap will have constant amortized search complexity as opposed to the logarithmic of a BST.

Also as you are talking about a huge tree here maybe you should take a look at [b+ trees](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree).

I doubt the approach you try to take will be more efficient than using the suggestions above. The depth of a binary tree grows very slowly(assuming it is balanced). On the other hand with your approach synchronization when you produce the output will be cumbersome.